# SQL: Select from another table (t2) without joining but referencing a column from t1

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a table with columns `date` and `net_sales`. For each day, I want to get the sum of the `net_sales` for the last 30 days.

This is my query:

```
  thirty_days_net_sales AS (
  SELECT
    t1.date,
    t1.net_sales AS net_sales_on_date,
    (SELECT SUM(t2.net_sales) FROM total_net_sales_per_day t2 WHERE t2.date >= DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t2.date <= t1.date)
  FROM
    total_net_sales_per_day t1)
```

When I run this query I get the error: `LEFT OUTER JOIN cannot be used without a condition that is an equality of fields from both sides of the join.`

I am using Google BigQuery. Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: @gordon-linoff what if I don't have data for every day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider rather below approach

```
select *, sum(net_sales) over win last_30_days
from total_net_sales_per_day
window win as (order by unix_date(date) range between 29 preceding and current row )
```

Comment: glad it works for you. consider also voting up the answer :o)

Answer (score 1):

You would use window functions.  If you have data for every day (as the name of the table implies:

```
SELECT tnspd.*
       sum(netsales) over (partition by date
                           order by date
                           rows between -30 and current row
                          )
FROM total_net_sales_per_day tnspd;
```

Answer (score 0):

As the error said, you have to add and equal condition. In case of using join you have to use ON keyword for one equal condition.

In your query, because you do not have join explicitly, you must have an equal condition something like I added below:

```
    thirty_days_net_sales AS (
      SELECT
        t1.date,
        t1.net_sales AS net_sales_on_date,
        (SELECT SUM(t2.net_sales) FROM total_net_sales_per_day t2 WHERE t2.date >= DATE_SUB(t1.date, INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND t2.date <= t1.date 
AND t1.id==t2.id)
      FROM
        total_net_sales_per_day t1)
```

This link might help for more information:

https://sql.info/d/solved-bigquery-left-outer-join-cannot-be-used-without-a-condition-that-is-an-equality-of-fields-from-both-sides-of-the-join